# What does it mean "not a valid LUKS device"?

Tags: installation, lvm, luks

During an upgrade from Fedora 15 to 17, I installed into an existing LUKS encrypted partition. I'm sure I borked the boot loader options, because the new system boots to GRUB. When I attempt to fix the problems from the boot cd and run `cryptsetup luksOpen /dev/sda3 cryptLVM`, I get that error.

I read about [header problems](http://www.linuxforums.org/forum/installation/188759-dev-md2-not-valid-luks-device.html#post890363) and the cryptsetup man page lists a "metadata repair" option for "benign" problems. I don't know what the trouble is and looking for the simplest answer. And yeah, I backed up (^_^)

Comment: Actaully its a seven year old laptop! woot! It takes me a year to fix an installation on the desktop every time I upgrade. Last time I skipped and went from Fedora 11 to 15 when fedora forums started ragging on me for EOL. Im seriously thinking of CentOS and a 10 year support so I don't have to do this every 6 mo.

Comment: Its like this. Linux just wants to, beggs, and cajoles the user to do more then they are capable of doing. LUKS is a whole new thing for me. I gripe, but I do enjoy Linux, only installation is not my favorite...

Comment: It's a lot better than it was 10 or 15 years ago.